# Why is XmlSerializer failing to initialize when mapping the object graph of classes with the same name, but different namespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I'm receiving XML from a third party that has no namespaces. The XML schema, in a simplified and obfuscated form, looks like the following:

```
<Root>
    <Address>
        <PostalCode>57373</PostalCode>
    </Address>
    <ReportAReport>
        <Address>
            <Zip>18573</Zip>
        </Address>
    </ReportAReport>
</Root>
```

Please take note that there are two distinct `Address` classes here. These are actually defined as two different `complexType`s, each in a spearate XML schema which I have received from the third party. One schema reflects the `Root` model, while the other schema reflects the model for `ReportAReport` Each `Address` class has distinct properties.

I represent each in a namespace, treating each XML schema as its own namespace. In fact, the schemas have namespaces defined, but the XML response I receive from the third party has chosen to omit these namespaces for some reason.

#### Namespace: MyCompany.MyProject

```
namespace MyCompany.MyProject
{
    public class Root
    {
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public ReportAReport ReportAReport { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Namespace: MyCompany.MyProject.ReportA

```
namespace MyCompany.MyProject.ReportA
{
    public class ReportAReport
    {
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Zip { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The exception I'm getting is as follows:

> Result Message:   Unable to create instance of class
>   MyCompany.MyProject.Test.AggregatorTests. Error:
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'MyCompany.MyProject.Test.AggregatorTests' threw an exception. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type
>   'MyCompany.MyProject.Root'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   There was an error reflecting property 'ReportAReport'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type
>   'MyCompany.MyProject.ReportA.ReportAReport'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting
>   property 'Address'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was
>   an error reflecting type 'MyCompany.MyProject.ReportA.Address'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Types
>   'MyCompany.MyProject.ReportA.Address' and
>   'MyCompany.MyProject.Address' both use the XML type name, 'Address',
>   from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name
>   and/or namespace for the type..

The line to which this exception is referring is as follows:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
```

The exception seems to be fairly clear about what is happening. The `XmlSerializer` is failing to understand to which `Address` class to map the property 'Address' in the `ReportAReport` class.

What I can't understand is why it is failing to understand to which `Address` class to map the property. In the class definition of `ReportAReport`, the 'Address' property is declared as being of type `MyCompany.MyProject.ReportA.Address`.

I even tried using `XmlElementAttribute` to specify the `Type` on `ReportAReport`:

```
[XmlElement(Type = typeof(Address))]
public Address Address { get; set; }
```

Though, that seems fairly redundant anyways...

### Question

The compiler clearly knows that `Address` here is referring to `MyCompany.MyProject.ReportA.Address`. Why is the `XmlSerializer` unable to make this discernment?

Shouldn't `XmlSerializer` know that if it encounters an `Address` node within a `ReportAReport` node, that it is of type `MyCompany.MyProject.ReportA.Address` rather than `MyCompany.MyProject.Address`?

What am I missing here?

---

I added the stack trace because it shows where the XmlSerializer initialization process is hiccuping. I actually pulled this stack trace from my real world example, which has a few nodes deeper than the samples, so there might be a few levels of recursion in the stack trace that don't seem to line up with the sample code I've provided.

```
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.GetTypeMapping(String typeName, String ns, TypeDesc typeDesc, NameTable typeLib, Type type)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportFieldMapping(StructModel parent, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportFieldMapping(StructModel parent, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateArrayElementsFromAttributes(ArrayMapping arrayMapping, XmlArrayItemAttributes attributes, Type arrayElementType, String arrayElementNs, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportArrayLikeMapping(ArrayModel model, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportFieldMapping(StructModel parent, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportFieldMapping(StructModel parent, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportFieldMapping(StructModel parent, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportFieldMapping(StructModel parent, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateArrayElementsFromAttributes(ArrayMapping arrayMapping, XmlArrayItemAttributes attributes, Type arrayElementType, String arrayElementNs, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportArrayLikeMapping(ArrayModel model, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportFieldMapping(StructModel parent, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElement(TypeModel model, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(Type type, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
   at MyCompany.MyProject.Test.AggregatorTests..cctor() in c:\Users\crush\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyCompany.MyProject\Test\MyCompany.MyProject.Test\AggregatorTests.cs:line 16
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at MyCompany.MyProject.Test.AggregatorTests..ctor()
```

---

*Update: I completely rewrote this question after realizing that my initial assessment about the exceptions I was receiving was completely incorrect. I negligently assumed that deserialization was the cause of the exception I was receiving, when in fact, it was clearly stated that initialization of the `XmlSerializer` was the problem. The question has been edited to state this fact, and I'm wiping the cake off my face as we speak. I apologize to anyone I misled with initial faulty and incomplete information.*

Comment: Why do you have the same exact class declared in two different namespaces?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I know that looks strange, I should add a few more properties to it to make it clear. They aren't the exact same class in reality. They share the same class name, but have different properties. And no, I don't want to come up with unique names for each class. The fact that they are in different namespaces should be enough for the XmlSerializer to resolve them.

Comment: Neither `Address` _belongs_ to any class. Your classes contain properties of a type named `Address`. There is nothing "proprietary" about them. They could as easily been some different class named `Address`, perhaps one not even defined by you.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't believe that is true. If the current node being deserialized is `Root`, and it encounters a child node named 'Address', then clearly, that corresponds to the Property of the `Root` class named 'Address'. Why would it be confused about the type of `Address` when `Address` is clearly defined on the `Root` class as `MyCompany.MyProject.Address` and not any other type of `Address`?

Comment: You are not taking into account that the XML may not match your class. Consider if an `<Address xmlns="foobar"/>` were found. Should an instance of your `Address` class be created? No, because that XML wasn't _from_ your `Address` class.

Comment: @JohnSaunders What are my options when there are no namespaces defined in the XML?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Also, in that case, I'd expect it not to create an instance of Address because no namespace has been defined. It seems like I'm interpreting the lack of a namespace to mean it should use the current namespace, but instead it defaults to empty namespace which would be the namespace of `Root` in this example? If that is the case, I still don't understand why it thinks `Address` is ambiguous. It should simply be tripping up on trying to assign an improper type to a property of a different type.

Comment: Please post the actual exception, including all InnerException instances. XmlSerializer is actually pretty good at showing the entire chain of exceptions.

Comment: @JohnSaunders That's going to be tough. Publishing that information would reveal sensitive information about the project and our sources that would get me in trouble. I'll try hard to make it anonymous without losing meaning...the actual deserialization is working on a much more deeply nested XML schema that the sample I've provided. The error message reflects this recursion as the name conflict is rather deep. It might be easier for me to just make a new project with the sample code above =/

Comment: It should be pretty easy to sanitize the exception. In the meantime you have us guessing instead of helping you.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I understand that. I'm doing my best to provide as much information as possible without revealing sensitive information. The excerpt generated is approximately 15 lines + another 65 if you include the stack trace. However, I just realized that I didn't do enough due diligence and the exception is coming from the initialization of the `XmlSerializer` and not the deserialization of the data. I'll be editing the question to reflect this, and I'll include the error message sanitized and relevant to my sample data. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @JohnSaunders I have revised the question. I'm still stumped on why this is happening, and what my options are to work around it. I've contacted the third party to ask them if they can start applying the namespaces, but have not heard back and it's been some time now. I'm assuming that I won't get those turned on. What options exist for working around this? Is my only option to use different class names? `Address1`, `Address2`, etc...

Comment: Note that there are many constructs of XmlSerializer. Maybe one of them can help. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.xmlserializer.aspx.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I see that I can pass a custom `XmlTypeMapping` as an argument. Is this the constructor that you were suggesting? That might work, but I'm still trying to understand why the mapping is failing automatically. Also, passing an array of Types doesn't seem to be an issue because it is running into a type conflict, rather than running into an unknown type.

Comment: I haven't used most of those constructors, so I don't know. I just remembered that there were many of them, so hoped one might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this model to de-serialize against. You can instantiate a new Address of either type and set the value from the deserialized model. You could use AutoMapper to accomplish the copy of objects

```
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Root
    {

        private RootAddress addressField;

        private RootReportAReport reportAReportField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public RootAddress Address
        {
            get
            {
                return this.addressField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.addressField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public RootReportAReport ReportAReport
        {
            get
            {
                return this.reportAReportField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.reportAReportField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RootAddress
    {

        private ushort postalCodeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public ushort PostalCode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.postalCodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.postalCodeField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RootReportAReport
    {

        private RootReportAReportAddress addressField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public RootReportAReportAddress Address
        {
            get
            {
                return this.addressField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.addressField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RootReportAReportAddress
    {

        private ushort zipField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public ushort Zip
        {
            get
            {
                return this.zipField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.zipField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```